# How to scroll from the first element to the second in recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How scroll from the first element to the second on click button? They are in different view holders and the button is in HeaderViewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder.itemViewType == HEADER_ITEM) {
        val viewHolder = holder as HeaderViewHolder
        holder.btn_next.setOnClickListener {
            println("Click on button")
        }
    } else {
        val viewHolder = holder as DefaultViewHolder
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Im add mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position + 1) and start the screen looks like this
[Start screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdbkv.png). After the first click on the button my screen looks like this [First pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZH3W.png). And only on the second pressed my screen [Second pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NxiQ.png).

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure you can access the recyclerview from that code.
You can look here for example of how to do that: [Is there a better way of getting a reference to the parent RecyclerView from the adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248529/is-there-a-better-way-of-getting-a-reference-to-the-parent-recyclerview-from-the)

Then simply call `scrollToPosition(position: Int)` on it. So in your example it could be done like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder.itemViewType == HEADER_ITEM) {
        val viewHolder = holder as HeaderViewHolder
        holder.btn_next.setOnClickListener {
            println("Click on button")
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position + 1)
        }
    } else {
        val viewHolder = holder as DefaultViewHolder
    }
}
```